# NEST query for Elasticsearch not working

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are using the NEST API to work with Elasticsearch using C#.
While we can insert data, queries which reference specific fields in an object are not working.

For example, given the following class:

```
internal class Magazine
{
   public Magazine(string id, string title, string author)
   {
      Id = id;
      Title = title;
      Author = author;
   }

   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Objects of the class are created and inserted into ElasticSearch as follows:

```
Magazine mag1= new Magazine("1", "Soccer Review", "John Smith");
Magazine mag2= new Magazine("2", "Cricket Review", "John Smith");

Uri node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "mag-application");
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);
client.Index(mag1);
client.Index(mag2);
```

The following query works, and returns two rows:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Magazine>(s => s.From(0).Size(20));
```

But this one returns nothing:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Magazine>(s => s.From(0).Size(20).Query(q => q.Term(p => p.Author, "John Smith")));
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the Standard analyzer (default option) the "John Smith" string is broken into 2 tokens "john" and "smith".

The term query :

> Matches documents that have fields that contain a term (not analyzed).

That is to say, the phrase that you are searching for will not pass from the aforementioned analysis process.

Try searching

```
client.Search<Magazine>(s => s.From(0).Size(20).Query(q => q.Term(p => p.Author, "john")));
```

or use a Match query like the one below:

```
client.Search<Magazine>(s => s.From(0).Size(20)..Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(p => p.Author).Query("John Smith"))
```

Check in the [official documentation for term query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-term-query.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first suggestion did not work, but the second one did.

Comment: I suppose that you tried with "john " in lowercase. "John" will not be found since the standard analyzer transforms all tokens into lowercase and that's how they live in Elasticsearch.

Comment: the second one works with changing OnField --> Field